# How can I get some of the data from the following URL?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to get some data from the following URLs like sunriseTime, outTemp, outsideHumidity and others.If you know how i can do this please help me.

**URL**
[enter link description here](http://www.metar.gr/ws/alexan/ZWNTANA.htm)

Comment: Have you researched how to get the contents of the website behind the url?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I could not find the data from there and that's why I chose it. If you want to see that URL and give some solution is this: (http://penteli.meteo.gr/stations/ioannina/)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Neither is *Here's a link to somewhere else. Go over there, see what I want to do, and then come back here and tell me how to do it*. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help], particularly [ask], before posting your next question here. Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate your response very much and I thank you for it. However, because I am new on this website and more generally in the field of programming, I do not know what queries you should mention and which not. Also i didn't know which code to use in the specific case,so I used this way to ask my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

- Open the URL
- Read the contents of the web page
- Create a pattern that you want to find in the data
- Use Regex (Regular Expression) to match the patterns you want from the data

I have written a Java program which does the above. Hope it helps :)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class URLReader {

    public static List<String> getAttributesFromURL(String urlString, 
                                                    String [] keys) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            //Opening the URL
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            // Reading the URL contents into a StringBuilder object
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Copying the StringBuilder contents into a string
        String contents = sb.toString();


        List<String> keyList = Arrays.asList(keys);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String key : keyList) {

            // Defining the pattern to be found in contents
            String patternToFind = key + "=\"(.*)\"";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternToFind);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(contents);
            if (m.find()) {

                // If pattern found, store them in the result list
                result.add(key + ": " + m.group(1).trim());
            }
        }
        // Returning the result
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String urlString ="http://www.metar.gr/ws/alexan/ZWNTANA.htm";

        // List all the keys whose values need to be extracted
        String[] keys = {"sunriseTime", "outsideTemp", "outsideHumidity"};

        // Getting the result
        List<String> attributeValuePairs = getAttributesFromURL(urlString, keys);
        System.out.println(attributeValuePairs);
    }
}
```

The output of the above program will be:

`[sunriseTime: 6:14, outsideTemp: 21.7, outsideHumidity: 57]`

You can get the values of other attributes you want by specifying the attribute names in the `keys`array in the program.

Comment: I have used your code and it does not show any problems but it does not return anything to me.

Comment: That's because I have just printed the result to the console. If you run it, you can see the output on the console. Could you tell me where you ran the program from?

Comment: From the Android Studio I run on my mobile phone

Comment: Did you check the console? I can change the program to return an ArrayList of the values. Would that help?

Comment: I have changed the program to return an ArrayList of the values. Please run it now and check :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but it still doesn't show me any effect.

Comment: I don't think you are calling it right. You should ideally paste your code along with your question so that people can give answers according to it.